# Qt 5.15.2, C++ QString indexOf() function problem

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator to develop a C++ application, I am trying to learn QString functions and i have problem with indexOf() function. I try to find "str" string in another string but this function always return the first index

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
int main()
{
    QString str = "Topic of today is QString String";
    QString y = "Str";
    int index;
    index = str.indexOf(y, 1);
    qDebug() << "index: " << index;
}
```

Comment: It always returns the first index because you use 1 as the second parameter of indexOf(). When you want the second match you need to use the previous index as the second parameter.

Comment: @drescherjm i know it indicates the first "Str" but i changed the number  many times but it still shows the first index. Also thanks for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always returns the first index because you use 1 as the second parameter of indexOf(). When you want the second match you need to use the previous index as the second parameter.

The following code shows how to find and display the first 2 matches.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
int main()
{
    QString str = "Topic of today is QString String";
    QString y = "Str";
    int index = 0;
    index = str.indexOf(y, index);
    qDebug() << "First index: " << index;
    if (index > 0) {
       index = str.indexOf(y, index+1);
       if (index > 0) qDebug() << "Second index: " << index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but when i execute this code  it returns the same problem which i have. First index: 19,  second index: 19.

Comment: index = str.indexOf(y, index + 1); Plus one, matters :)

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o that was going to be my first thought but I wanted to verify.

Answer (score 1):

indexOf returns the first index that matches from the startfrom offset you gave (1).

If you want to get all indexes, you need to call indexOf with the startfrom set to the last index found + 1 repeatedly until you find no more occurrences.

Comment: Thanks, i undestood i will try.